# Spray multiple post parameters

Tags: scala, rest, akka, spray

How to handle more than one parameter in the post body. To handle one I do:

```
post {
            respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) {
              entity(as[String]) { text =>
                complete(extract(text).toJson.compactPrint)
              }
            }
          }
```

Now I need to get a seconds double parameter.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define case class with your desired two fields

```
case class MyClass(first: String, second: Double)
```

create Json format for MyClass

```
object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val formatMyClass = jsonFormat2(MyClass)
}
```

Spray will deserialize json to MyClass

```
post {
   respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) {
              entity(as[MyClass]) { myClass =>
                complete(extract(text).toJson.compactPrint)
              }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what if I want to make second optional?

Comment: Make a the second parameter Option: case class MyClass(first: String, second: Option[Double])

Comment: Thank you sir. As a note, don't forget to: import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._ and MyJsonProtocol in the routes.